# Change background color from slot PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to be able to change the color of my application from a slot. For example, if user enters the wrong data into `qlabel` the whole QWidget turns to red color.

It is easy just to change color in code before method `show()`, like this:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
p = window.palette()
p.setColor(window.backgroundRole(), QtCore.Qt.red)
window.setPalette(p)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I do not know how to change the color in slot, if I have this structure:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent) 
        uic.loadUi("file.ui", self)
        self.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.change_color)

    # what should be in change-color slot?
    def change_color(self):
        #.....?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Should I somehow call a pointer of QWidget in slot ?

What is the way to achieve proper functionality here?

Comment: "Should I somehow call a pointer of QWidget in slot ?"  Sure you should. It's called self in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance of the class is the first parameter that you pass to your methods and in your case is `self`, so you must do the following:

```
def checks(self):
    p = self.palette()
    p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QtCore.Qt.red)
    self.setPalette(p)
```